# Testing USA SIM & Mobile Phone Number from UK

Tags: android, ios, mobile, sim-card

I'm a UK based IOS / Android developer and want to test SMS capability to a US mobile phone number(e.g. many google services offer SMS capability only to US numbers)

Does anyone have a recommended way of doing this?  At the moment, I'm looking at just buying a pre-paid US SIM and putting it into an old unlocked tri / quad band phone.  But perhaps someone has walked this path before and has a better way of doing things?

Comment: No better way for me - I just found co-workers or relatives of friends who lived there and had them try it out. I tried buying phone and shipping it to the US, only to discover the SMS didn't work although the phone did. Goofy stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks for the input Matt.  I've sent off a bunch of emails to global SIM companies...for now.  Thanks the input on the phone idea though -- I'll make sure to stay away from that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in charge of technology for simstogo, we are providers of global roaming SIMs. 
I would not test any SMS delivery using global SIMs if you are specifically testing US, exceptions apply but the safe way to do it is using a SIM from a US operator. 
If you need some more details please get in touch, roberto.carballa@simstogo.co.uk